# RESTful way to request an action?

Tags: rest

If part of my RESTful api like looks like this:

```
POST transactions?auth_code=[code]
```

and part of this post is an email address so the server can send a receipt and at a later time the client wants to have the receipt sent again, how would I create the API for that? The server returns a transactionID from the POST. Should I do something like this:

```
PUT transactions/[transactionID]?auth_code=[code]&requestReceipt=YES
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would invert the POST/PUT calls. PUT to create something new (in this case a transaction with an email address) and POST to resend the receipt. If POST in that endpoint (/transactions/[transactionID]) is only used to resend the confirmation, I would omit the requestReceipt parameter.

Comment: Because the server is creating the transactionID, POST is appropriate. You are right in that I should use a POST to alter the existing transaction because I am not replacing the entire transaction with a new one.